# MVC model binding keeps values NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get custom model binding to work, but for some reason the values aren't set. The code seems ligit when comparing it to working code, but still it doesnt bind. I guess it some trivial thing i'm missing.

Custom model:

```
//Cluster is from Entity Framework

//BaseViewModelAdmin defines:
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MenuItems;
public IPrincipal CurrentUser = null;
public Foundation Foundation; //also from Entity Framework

public class AdminClusterCreateModel : BaseViewModelAdmin
{
    public Cluster Item;
    public AdminClusterCreateModel()
    {
        Item = new Cluster();
    }
}
```

The view form looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  <fieldset>
      <legend>Cluster</legend>

      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item.Active)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item.Active)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item.Active)
      </div>


      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item.Name)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item.Name)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item.Name)
      </div>

      <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Create" />
      </p>
  </fieldset>
}
```

And the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AdminClusterCreateModel model, FormCollection form)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid) //true
    {
        var test = form["Item.Name"]; //Value is correct from form (EG: Test)
        UpdateModel(model);  //no error
    }

    //At this point model.Item.Name = null <--- WHY?

    return View(model);
}
```

Cluster on request

```
public partial class Cluster
{
    public Cluster()
    {
        this.Team = new HashSet<Team>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public long FoundationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Foundation Foundation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Team { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your Cluster class? Is Item.Name definitely a public property rather than a public field? It's been a while but IIRC it will only bind to properties.

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: Have you checked if there is something in `UpdateModel` that updates `model.Item`?

Comment: How can I check that? @Marco can you explain what makes this so poor?

Comment: These models look pretty standard to me, so I too am curious why Marco thinks they suck.

Comment: Can you show the http request for Create (from firebug or google webdeveloper console)?

Comment: Don't take me wrong @HugoDelsing, because even MSFT advices its use, but this is completelly wrrong in an MVC point of view: (AdminClusterCreateModel model, FormCollection form). In a proper MVC environment, the client submits an action to a controller, with that action the controller, does some work, and based on that feedback a Model is built, which is then forwarded to the view. How come then, does the controller get a model from the client? Complete wrong semantics.

Comment: Is the custom model binder is registered and executes when data are posted? because if not and DefaultModelBinder is still binding the data, AFAIK the 'Item' has to be a 'Property' rather than 'Field' in the 'AdminClusterCreateModel' class.

Comment: That's still exactly what is happening in this case Marco, only that the data passed as part of the action request is being bound to a specified object (in this case, a model) automatically for use by the controller action so that it can be manipulated as necessary. The semantics are only a problem if you view the model as been having passed by the client, rather than recognising it for what it is - that data passed by the client has been automatically bound to a model as part of the action request.

Comment: @shakib i'm quite new to c# MVC and I've noticed that sometimes you need to enable things in other places before something works. Your remark about "is the custom model binder registered" leads me to believe I need to enable something for this to work, but I cannot find what that is. Can you explain what I need to enable and where to make this work (Perhaps as answer so I can give proper credits if it helps)? My preference would be for this to work for all custom models and not that I need to alter them all.

Comment: @HugoDelsing by default 'DefaultModelBinder' comes into play and constructs the object in action method parameter from 'FormCollection'. There is a way to alter binding works for a specific type by 'Custom Model Binder'(relevant http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228826/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binders). I asked about it because maybe i misread 'I'm trying to get custom model binding to work'. Now i think there is no 'Custom Binder' and 'DefaultModelBinder' is still playing the role. In that case you might want to change 'public Cluster Item;' to 'public Cluster Item {get; set;};' to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed `public Cluster Item {get; set;}` was enough to make it work. My apoligies for the misleading info. I was binding to a custom model, so thats why I used that term. if you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @HugoDelsing posted as answer :)

Comment: Well spotted shakib! I had the right suspicion, but on the wrong property (well, field) it seems :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DefaultModelBinder works explicitly on 'Properties', not on 'Fields'

Changing `public Cluster Item` to `public Cluster Item {get; set;}` in `AdminClusterCreateModel` should do the trick.

```
public class AdminClusterCreateModel : BaseViewModelAdmin
{
    public Cluster Item {get; set;}

    public AdminClusterCreateModel()
    {
        Item = new Cluster();
    }
 }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is a *trivial* and a *corner case*, yet if it might help someone:

If your model has a property, named **model**  this to will cause the DefaultModelBinder to return a null.

```
public class VehicleModel
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```